# Save xml data response [swift]

Tags: xml, swift

This is the xml response that i return from api:

```
<item>
        <sku>JC-0000000004780</sku>
        <name>Moco Black Bean Drink</name>
        <description></description>
        <delivery_time>24 hours</delivery_time>
        <img_1></img_1>
        <img_2></img_2>
        <img_3></img_3>
        <thumb_1></thumb_1>
        <thumb_2></thumb_2>
        <thumb_3></thumb_3>
        <vid_1></vid_1>
        <qr_code>JC4780</qr_code>
        <zone_records>1</zone_records>
        <delivery_zones>
                <zone>3</zone>
                <zone_name>Within Klang Valley</zone_name>
        </delivery_zones>
        <price_records>1</price_records>
        <price_option>
            <option>
                <id>9645</id>
                <label>190ml</label>
                <price>4.13</price>
                <promo_price>0</promo_price>
                <qty>50</qty>
                <stock>0.00</stock>
                <stock_unit></stock_unit>
                <default>TRUE</default>
                <p_weight>0</p_weight>
            </option>
        </price_option>
        <related_products></related_products>
        <freshness></freshness>
        <bulk>0</bulk>
        <halal>0</halal>
    </item>
    <item>
        <sku>JC-0000000004779</sku>
        <name>Hongcho Vinegar Drink Pomegranate </name>
        <description></description>
        <delivery_time>24 hours</delivery_time>
        <img_1></img_1>
        <img_2></img_2>
        <img_3></img_3>
        <thumb_1></thumb_1>
        <thumb_2></thumb_2>
        <thumb_3></thumb_3>
        <vid_1></vid_1>
        <qr_code>JC4779</qr_code>
        <zone_records>1</zone_records>
        <delivery_zones>
                <zone>3</zone>
                <zone_name>Within Klang Valley</zone_name>
        </delivery_zones>
        <price_records>2</price_records>
        <price_option>
            <option>
                <id>9696</id>
                <label>500ml</label>
                <price>23.50</price>
                <promo_price>21.37</promo_price>
                <qty>50</qty>
                <stock>0.00</stock>
                <stock_unit></stock_unit>
                <default>TRUE</default>
                <p_weight>0</p_weight>
            </option>
            <option>
                <id>9644</id>
                <label>900ml</label>
                <price>38.50</price>
                <promo_price>0</promo_price>
                <qty>50</qty>
                <stock>0.00</stock>
                <stock_unit></stock_unit>
                <default>FALSE</default>
                <p_weight>0</p_weight>
            </option>
        </price_option>
        <related_products></related_products>
        <freshness></freshness>
        <bulk>0</bulk>
        <halal>0</halal>
    </item>
```

The tricky problem is the price_records part, some items will only return 1 price records and some will return 2 price records and so on (as the response that i provide), how to save it so? I am using SWXMLHash library

Comment: After parsing the xml using SWXMLHash, you will need to iterate over the xml and use the data accordingly. Fro example, in your iterations, if you see the price_records key holds n number of price_options, then access price_options n times to get all price options.

Comment: can you show me how? @RoyK

Answer (score 1):

```
let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)

for item in xml["item"] { // Iterate over items
    if let priceRecordsValue = item["price_records"].element?.text { // Check if price_records value exist
        let priceRecordsCount = Int(priceRecordsValue) ?? 1 // Keep amount of price records in form of Int, default is 1
        for index in 0...(priceRecordsCount-1) { // Iterate over the amount of price records
            if let optionElement = item["price_option"]["option"][index].element { // Check if option element[n] exists
                // Do something with option element[n] here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i debug, it won't loop into the line " if let optionElement = item["price_option"]["options"][index].element { // Check if option element[n] exists
                // Do something with option element[n] here
            }"

Comment: @bobo First, try now, I've made a little change. Secondly, you should not expect one to give you code to work with your project. Take this code and play with it, try, change, learn it, that way you will become a better developer. :)